# remove files within specific time range

Tags: bash

I have a directory of several files, and each file contains a timestamp at the end of its name, in the format of `.%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S`, like following

```
filename.2021-02-12T10-29-59
filename.2021-02-11T05-04-30
filename.2021-02-10T00-12-30
filename.2021-02-10T20-30-30
...
```

I'm writing a script that whose timestamp is 3 days older than the current date.
For example, if current date is 2021-02-10 (from `date '+%Y-%m-%d'` command), it should delete all files older than 2021-02-07.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with GNU awk and xargs:

```
awk -F\. '{ newdat=gensub("[T-]"," ","g",$2);if (mktime(newdat)<( strftime("%s")-259200)) { print $0 } }' <(for i in filename*;do echo $i;done) | xargs rm
```

Loop on the files in the directory with the name *.filename and redirect the output back into awk. Take the second "." delimited field and replace all "T" and "-" characters, with a space, reading the result into a variable newdat. This is then used for the mktime function to compare the date in epoch format to the current epoch format date (attained with strftime) minus 259200 (seconds in 3 days). If the difference is greater than 3 days, print the filename and pipe the output through to xargs rm to remove the file(s)

Use xargs echo as opposed to rm to first verify that the files are listed as expected.